# relationship betwen data and client socket

Tags: php, sockets, server, client

I wanted to know if I can know the client information already connected when he sends me a message, I use the php socket; for example :
client (A) connects to the server (there I can know his information with socket_getpeername) after client (B) connects and client (C) connects ...., if one of the connected clients sends me a message I wanted it stored in the database (I do not know who will send me the message first)
I can store the ID of the first connection but how can I know the information of the 2nd connection of the same client to compare them with the stored id and know who is the client ?

Comment: Assign an ID to them when they connect and send that to the server

Comment: but the server how will he know the 2nd message client.... exemple : 
client (A) connects -> ID = 1
client (B) connects -> ID = 2
client (C) connects -> ID = 3
------
client (A or B or C) sends a message -> how can I know who sent this message?

Comment: I used google translate, when you send the message it will be an event send the ID along with it store the ID in a cookie on the client side and a session in the server side. And I'm not that familiar with php but logic wise this would definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I explain: the client (box GPS) sends its identifier (IMEI) and it waits for the answer of the server (message '01'), after receiving(message'01') the client sends the data to the server and the server stores them in the database. here it works well with only one client and even with several clients connected but the problem if at the time the server wait for the data GPS client (A), another client (B) connects, so the server when he receives the data GPS of client (A) , he will store them with the name of client (B) because in my code the server stores the GPS data with the name of the last connected client.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

$ip='192.168.1.1';
$port=135;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) ;
socket_bind($sock, $ip , $port) ;

socket_listen ($sock);

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";
$tab=array();
$client = array($sock);
while (true)
{
              $read = $client;
              $write=null ;
              $except=null ;
 if(socket_select($read , $write , $except , 0)<1)
              continue;

 if (in_array($sock, $read))
  {
              $client[] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);
              socket_getpeername($newsock, $address, $port) ;
              echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
              echo "Waiting for incoming data... \n";
              $key = array_search($sock, $read);
              unset($read[$key]);
     }

  foreach ($read as $read_sock)
   {
    $input = socket_read($read_sock, 102401,PHP_BINARY_READ) ;

     if ($input == false)
       {
           $key = array_search($read_sock, $client);
           unset($client[$key]);
           echo "client disconnected.\n";
           continue;
        }
        if(!empty($input))
        {
            if(strlen($input)==17){
            //$input=bin2hex($input) ;
            $input = substr($input,2,strlen($input));

            $imei_verif=$input ;
            echo "Le 1er socket reçu : \n";
            echo  "IMEI =$input"."\n"."length=".strlen($input);


            //$response=hex2bin('01');
            $response='01';
            echo "\n La réponse est 01 \n";
           $len = strlen($response);

           $res_write=socket_send($read_sock ,$response,$len,0);
           echo "GPS informations ....... \n";
           $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "fma120");
           $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM vehicule WHERE imei='$imei_verif'");
           $outp = $result->fetch_assoc();
           $identifiant= $outp['identifiant'] ;
           $matricule=$outp['matricule'];
           echo $identifiant."\n";
           echo $matricule;
            }



            else {
                echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
                $input=bin2hex($input) ;
                $payload=$input ;
                $crc = substr($payload, strlen($payload) - 8, 8);

                echo "crc = ".$crc ."\n" ;

                $avlDataWithChecks = substr($payload, 16, -8);
                if (substr($avlDataWithChecks, 2, 2) !== substr($avlDataWithChecks, strlen($avlDataWithChecks) - 2, 2))
                {
                    echo "First element count check is different than last element count check \n ";
                    echo " informations = " .$input ."\n" ;

                }

                if(substr($avlDataWithChecks, 2, 2) == substr($avlDataWithChecks, strlen($avlDataWithChecks) - 2, 2) )
                {

                    echo"voila ....................... GPS informations réçu : \n" ;

                    echo"input = ".$input ."\n" ;
                    echo "length=".strlen($input);
                    echo "avlDataWithChecks = ".$avlDataWithChecks ."\n" ;

                    $numberOfElements = hexdec(substr($avlDataWithChecks, 2, 2));
                    echo "numberOfElements = " .$numberOfElements ."\n" ;
                    $avlData = substr($avlDataWithChecks, 4, -2);


                    $position = 0;
                    $resultData = [];


                    $dateTime = new DateTime();
                    $timestamp = hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 16)) / 1000;
                    $timestamp+= 7200;
                    echo "timestamp =".$timestamp . "\n";
                    $dateTime -> setTimestamp(intval($timestamp));
                    echo "dateteTime = " .$dateTime->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
                    $position += 16;



                    $priority = (int)hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 2));
                    echo" priority = " .$priority ."\n" ;
                    $position += 2;

                    $longitude = substr($avlData, $position, 8);
                    $longitude = (float)(hexdec($longitude) / 10000000);
                    echo" longitude = " .$longitude ."\n" ;
                    $position += 8;

                    $latitude = substr($avlData, $position, 8);
                    $latitude = (float)(hexdec($latitude) / 10000000);
                    echo" latitude = " .$latitude ."\n" ;
                    $position += 8;

                    $altitude = (int)hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 4));
                    echo" altitude = " .$altitude ."\n" ;
                    $position += 4;

                    $angle = (int)hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 4));
                    echo" angle = " .$angle ."\n" ;
                    $position += 4;

                    $satellites = (int)hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 2));
                    echo" satellites = " .$satellites ."\n" ;
                    $position += 2;

                    $speed = (int)hexdec(substr($avlData, $position, 4));
                    echo" speed = " .$speed ."\n" ;

                    echo "\n La réponse est $numberOfElements \n";


                    $output = sprintf("%08X", $numberOfElements) ;
                    $output2=$output ;
                    echo "avant l'envoie = " .$output2 ."\n" ;

                    $output2 =hex2bin($output2);


                    $len = strlen($output2);

                    $res_write=socket_send($read_sock,$output2,$len,0);

                    echo "apres l'envoie = " .$output2 ."\n" ;
                    //echo $identifiant."\n";
                    //$output2 =hex2bin($output2);


                    $len = strlen($output2);

                    $res_write=socket_send($read_sock ,$output2,$len,0);

                    echo "apres l'envoie = " .$output2 ."\n" ;
                    try
                    {
                        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fma120;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                    }
                    $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO gps_data(client,matricule,imei, timestamp, longitude, latitude, altitude,angle,satellites,speed,etat,n_of_elem) VALUES('$identifiant','$matricule','$imei_verif', '$timestamp', '$longitude', '$latitude', '$altitude','$angle','$satellites','$speed','0','$numberOfElements')");


                    echo 'Strored in the data base';
                }
                }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

the problem is the gps data does not contain any information about the client so i can not know this data is related to which client, maybe if i know the ip address of the message source and after I compare it with the ip address of the first connection (when the client sends the imei).
I can store the ID of the first connection but how can I know the information of the 2nd connection of the same client to compare them with the stored id ?